# How to configure the REDSHIFT program so that it does not change the brightness of the screen?

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, external-monitor, redshift

For "Night Light" I use Redshift software. Unfortunately, this program automatically changes the brightness of the external monitor to the default value: the value in the Lubuntu system settings is ignored. How to ensure that the RedShift program does not change the monitor brightness system settings?

Here is my redshift config file:

```
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=3300
temp-night=3300

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature
transition=0

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'gnome-clock', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=manual

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings
; e.g. 'redshift -l manual:help'
[manual]
lat=43
lon=1

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the second screen.
[randr]
screen=0
```

As you can see, the program is set so that the monitor temperature is always the same: day and night. That's the way it's supposed to be.

Thank you.

Comment: You've not provided any release details; nor which `redshift` you're using (redshift-qt, redshift-gtk etc), but I created my *conf* file back in ~15.04 with MATE & have used the same file with all releases/DEs including my current Lubuntu/LXQt without issue (*or hardware*). I didn't look at your file as I have starting reference point (*what release the template should match*).  Also are you sure you've not got the app being run twice (*that can case it to misbehave!*)

Comment: Sorry. It is latest available redshift-gtk version. My system release datails are: Distributor ID: Ubuntu; Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; Codename:       jammy
 (output of lsb_release -a commant)

Comment: redshift 1.12 (version)